# Possible parsing error from a class method

Tags: c#, parsing

So I'm trying to return a decimal value for a total cost of a bill into a textbox from a class method.

this class method is as shown:

```
public decimal calcCost(decimal totalCost, bool specialistRepair, decimal labourHours,      decimal standardRate, decimal partSaleCost)
    {

        foreach (Job j in m_jobs)
        {
            if (specialistRepair == true)
            {
                totalCost = totalCost + 45;
            }

            totalCost = totalCost + partSaleCost + (labourHours * standardRate);
        }

        return totalCost;
    }
```

the problem I'm having is that it's saying 'Cannot implicitly comvert type 'decimal to 'string'.

I have tried parsing the whole line after the '=' sign but that's not possible.

```
txtTotal.Text = //Here// Program.AuspexDo.calcCost(0, checkSpecialist, jobHours, standardRate, partSaleCost);
```

The code for main is shown here:

```
      bool checkSpecialist = true;
        if (chkSpecialistRepairs.Checked == true)
        {
            checkSpecialist = true;

        }

        decimal jobHours = decimal.Parse(txtHours.Text); 
        decimal standardRate = Program.AuspexDo.StandardRate;
        decimal partSaleCost = 5; //to be configured



        txtTotal.Text = Program.AuspexDo.calcCost(0, checkSpecialist, jobHours, standardRate, partSaleCost);
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have 'Cannot implicitly comvert type 'decimal to 'string'.' I'll make it clearer

Comment: I would pass "m_jobs" to the method and not modify a parameter "totalCost" and return that modified value but rather use a local decimal for the the calculation - but the .ToString() is the real issue (you might need to format the decimal as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
txtTotal.Text = Program.AuspexDo.calcCost(0, checkSpecialist, jobHours, standardRate, partSaleCost).ToString();
```

Comment: Oh wow, I wouldn't have thought to have done that, it's not showing an error, I'll check it does what I want it too.

Answer (score 1):

`calcCost` returns a `decimal` and you are trying to assign the return value to `txtTotal.Text`, which is of type `string`.

As the error says, there is no conversion between the two - you need to convert the return value to a `string` first - the way to do that is to call `ToString()` on the return value:

```
txtTotal.Text = Program.AuspexDo.calcCost(0, 
                                          checkSpecialist, 
                                          jobHours, 
                                          standardRate, 
                                          partSaleCost)
                                          .ToString();
```

Take a look at the [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) numeric format strings, as well as the information about [composite format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx), as you may want to output to a specific format.